# Rails: auto increment column with scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have projects and issues. The issue number (not ID) must be auto-increment but scoped with project_id. Any gem or easy way to accomplish that? Thank you!

Edit: acts_as_list will do the job, but what if a record is deleted? The next issue will be with it's number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Issue class:

```
belongs_to :project
before_validation( :on => :create ) do 
  self.issue_number = self.project.issues.collect { | issue | issue.issue_number }.max + 1
end
```

(or thereabouts) -- essentially, before the new object is created, find the max issue number of the issues associated with the issue's project, increment that, and use it for the new issue number...

Comment: I guess I need to have number field in the projects table, and just to increment that, because otherwise if something is deleted the next one will have its number. However, this approach is neat. Thank you.

Comment: it's not uncommon to simply set "destroyed_on" for a record (instead of actually deleting it) and apply a "live" scope to most queries against that class.  If you do this, then you can include deleted records in your query to determine the next issue number.

Comment: Just be aware that this may be subject to a race condition if creating multiple models at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the counter_cache on the Project issues association and override Project's decrement_counter to do nothing.